# Google DistanceMatrix API usage

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

This is not a coding question. Rather a general question.

Using Google Distance Matrix API to calculate driving distance between two places in VBA to be recorded in excel.

According to Terms of Service, it needs to be done in conjunction with Google Maps. So is it not possible that I only want to record the distance in my excel file?

Comment: Questions to terms of service do not really belong here (probably better in some law exchange ;) ? ). But yes, this is not allowed with Google Maps API, search for alternatives...

Comment: Cheers. Will do. Thankyou so much for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be done entirely in your VBA code but it is possible using the Google Web Service with VB or C# from a middle tier application that your VBA code can call. There are limits on how many calls you can make depending on if you are doing this "free" or if you have a Premium license as we do.

Each address request has to be signed which the google documents will show you how to do. In your VB code you can use a System.Net.WebRequest to make calls to the Google Web Service using the base URL `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?`

Read More here:
[Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the WebRequest using C# but I can't find what you mean by **Each address request has to be signed**. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: That is my fault. We use it in conjunction with the Geocode API and it all ran together in my head. The Matrix you just need a origin Lat/Lon and your destination Lat/Lon. I apologize for the confusion.